# Can we calculate the Surface tones at runtime in android

Tags: android, material-design

First things first Surface color is not static. Here is the [documentation](https://m3.material.io/styles/color/the-color-system/color-roles#c0cdc1ba-7e67-4d6a-b294-218f659ff648) from Material 3 that says when a surface is elevated the color of the Surface changes via an overlay of the primary color. Since I am displaying my app via edge to edge by making the system bars transparent I would like to determine the color of my surface on a particular elevation.